# Can I train skills (planche, handstand, etc) in the evening and dips at a later time of the day?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises

I have been working out for a year and have started to do more body-weight training four months ago. I want to achieve skills that are chest-, triceps- and shoulder-oriented. But I also want to get a strong dip. Is it then okay to train for planche  in the morning, and then do dips later on the same day? For example, at 1 p.m. I do planche training, then at 9 p.m. I do dip training?

Comment: Is there anything in particular you're worried about? Questions starting with "Can I...?" are usually answered by "of course, unless there's something in particular stopping you".

Comment: Im worried about over training and injuries in particular because im working on the same muscles twice a day. Msybe I should rewrite and put "should" instead

Comment: I have a question, why would you want to do them in seperate workouts rather than just doing a shoulder / tricep / chest workout that involves both plance and dips? For me, dips is usually part of my planche workout. What would you see as a benefit for doing them seperate?

Comment: Because I feel so fatigued after my planche workout I feel I cant perform well enough on the dips

Answer (score 1):

Working on the same muscles twice a day is perfectly fine, but you want to do it a certain way.. Leave at least 8 hours in between both workouts, and save all the hard exercises like ones with a lot of weight(in terms of bodyweight, ones like a planche is harder than dips), or compound exercises, and save isolation exercises and easier exercises for your night workout. What you're doing is fine, keep in mind working out twice a day may require you to recover more